# Search and replace in xib file

Tags: ios, perl, shell, grep

I am trying to search a text in some of the xibs in my project and replace the found text with some other text. I am using below mentioned command to perform the mentioned action but it is saying

> "grep: warning: recursive search of stdin" and going to infinite waiting state.

```
grep -i -r --include=*.xib “$MSAwLjMxMTU4NDA0NDMgMC4wOTczNjMxNzM3NQA" myProjectPath | sort | uniq | xargs perl -e “s/$MSAwLjMxMTU4NDA0NDMgMC4wOTczNjMxNzM3NQA/$MC4xNTI5NDExODIzIDAuODA3ODQzMjA4MyAwLjE4MDM5MjE2MQA/" -pi
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please, fix the quotes.

Comment: Which quotes, Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The curly quotes (“) where you almost certainly used straight quotes (") in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The shell is expanding `$MSAwLjMxMTU4NDA0NDMgMC4wOTczNjMxNzM3NQA`as a variable and grep is producing output in the form "file: ", which `sort | uniq` is not correcting.

```
grep -l -i -r --include=*.xib '\$MSAwLjMxMTU4NDA0NDMgMC4wOTczNjMxNzM3NQA' myProjectPath | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\$MSAwLjMxMTU4NDA0NDMgMC4wOTczNjMxNzM3NQA/\$MC4xNTI5NDExODIzIDAuODA3ODQzMjA4MyAwLjE4MDM5MjE2MQA/' "$file"
```